# Bug in my brain or in pyplot? Whiskers in boxplot with iqr zero

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, iqr

Using

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,-10]
matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot(x)
```

plots the following: [image]

Where the whiskers are invisible at -10 and 10.
The definition according to the documentation however states that the whiskers are at Q1-1.5 * IQR and at Q1+1.5 * IQR. Shouldn't they be at 0 then, too?

Is this a bug, or did I misunderstand something about box plots?

Answer (score 0):

See matplotlib [issue 5331](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5331)

Was considered a feature. Is solved in currently still unstable 2.0.